# Cross Domain Policy troubles non port 80 in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cross-domain

I'm having trouble accessing my web service from Unity if it is not running on port 80. This is the C# code that I'm using in Unity

```
private void RunSimulation()
{
    string url = @"http://192.168.1.116:9000/simulate";
    WWW goServer = new WWW(url);
}
```

On 192.168.1.116, I have a program written in go that is listening on port 9000. I can easily reach this URL from a web browser and I will get my expected result.

When I try this in Unity, if I examine the contents of my goServer variable, I will see the message

> System.Security.Exception: No valid crossdomain policy available to allow access

There is a crossdomain policy file. It is located at /var/www/html/crossdomain.xml Is has the following contents:

```
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
```

This file existed before and there were .php programs that were able to successfully be called. I added the to-ports"*" to try to get it to work, but no luck.

I have tried having my go server listen on port 80. When I do this, I am able to connect from Unity. Any idea?

---

```
(The input sanitizer is defeating me and I can't figure out how to post without the input form telling me that my links are not allowed, so I'm going to omit 192.168.1.116:9000)
```

I was not getting anything at serverurl.com:9000/crossdomain.xml
So I put some code into my go server to respond to this request and return a response with headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials.

I set the ENABLE_CROSSDOMAIN_LOGGING environment variable. I see this in the log file plus a bunch more

Determining crossdomain.xml location for request: /simulate?asdfa=sadfsa

About to parse url: /simulate?asdfa=sadfsa

Determining crossdomain.xml location for request:/simulate?asdfa=sadfsa

About to parse url: /crossdomain.xml

About to parse url: /simulate?asdfa=sadfsa

```
Determining crossdomain.xml location for request: /simulate?asdfa=sadfsa

Download had OK statuscode

Received the following crossdomain.xml

----------



----------

received policy

BuildFlashPolicy caught an exception while parsing
/crossdomain.xml: Policy can't be constructed from empty stream.
```

ArgumentException: Policy can't be constructed from empty stream.
at MonoForks.System.Windows.Browser.Net.FlashCrossDomainPolicy.FromStream (System.IO.Stream originalStream) [0x00000] in :0 
at MonoForks.System.Windows.Browser.Net.CrossDomainPolicyManager.BuildFlashPolicy (Boolean statuscodeOK, MonoForks.System.Uri uri, System.IO.Stream responsestream, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 responseheaders) [0x00000] in :0 
UnityEngine.WWW:get_assetBundle()
PlayEditorMain:RunSimulation() (at Assets\Scripts\Play Editor Scripts\Menu Scripts\PlayEditorMain.cs:526)
PlayEditorMain:ButtonPressed(GameObject) (at Assets\Scripts\Play Editor Scripts\Menu Scripts\PlayEditorMain.cs:261)
MainMenuButton:OnClick() (at Assets\Scripts\Play Editor Scripts\Menu Buttons\MainMenuButton.cs:23)
UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions)
UICamera:Notify(GameObject, String, Object) (at Assets\3rd Party\NGUI\Scripts\UI\UICamera.cs:765)
UICamera:ProcessTouch(Boolean, Boolean) (at Assets\3rd Party\NGUI\Scripts\UI\UICamera.cs:1435)
UICamera:ProcessMouse() (at Assets\3rd Party\NGUI\Scripts\UI\UICamera.cs:1063)
UICamera:Update() (at Assets\3rd Party\NGUI\Scripts\UI\UICamera.cs:909)

(Filename: Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs Line: 526)

Unable to determine the audio type from the URL (/simulate?asdfa=sadfsa) . Please specify the type.
UnityEngine.WWW:GetAudioClip(Boolean, Boolean, AudioType)
UnityEngine.WWW:GetAudioClip(Boolean, Boolean) (at C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\artifacts\EditorGenerated\Utils.cs:308)
UnityEngine.WWW:GetAudioClip(Boolean) (at C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\artifacts\EditorGenerated\Utils.cs:301)
UnityEngine.WWW:get_audioClip() (at C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\artifacts\EditorGenerated\Utils.cs:293)
PlayEditorMain:RunSimulation() (at Assets\Scripts\Play Editor Scripts\Menu Scripts\PlayEditorMain.cs:526)
PlayEditorMain:ButtonPressed(GameObject) (at Assets\Scripts\Play Editor Scripts\Menu Scripts\PlayEditorMain.cs:261)
MainMenuButton:OnClick() (at Assets\Scripts\Play Editor Scripts\Menu Buttons\MainMenuButton.cs:23)
UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String, Object, SendMessageOptions)
UICamera:Notify(GameObject, String, Object) (at Assets\3rd Party\NGUI\Scripts\UI\UICamera.cs:765)
UICamera:ProcessTouch(Boolean, Boolean) (at Assets\3rd Party\NGUI\Scripts\UI\UICamera.cs:1435)
UICamera:ProcessMouse() (at Assets\3rd Party\NGUI\Scripts\UI\UICamera.cs:1063)
UICamera:Update() (at Assets\3rd Party\NGUI\Scripts\UI\UICamera.cs:909)

[C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Audio/AudioClip.cpp line 118] 
(Filename: Assets/Scripts/Play Editor Scripts/Menu Scripts/PlayEditorMain.cs Line: 526)

So I think I am now returning the correct headers, but I'm thinking that I also need to return the contents in the body. I'm thinking that I'll just return the same contents that the crossdomain.xml file I get when I query it on port 80.

I know that the crossdomain.xml endpoint on my server is being hit. If I understand what the logfile that unity is outputting, the problem might just be that the body is empty and I have an empty stream.

Comment: See what actual file Unity requests (i.e. use Fiddler to capture requests). There is a chance that it asks for file at different location than you expect.

Comment: I do want to try this, but I have not yet been able to make unity use a proxy. It is easy to set a proxy for chrome and inspect the traffic in Fiddler, but I have not yet been able to get this working for Unity.

Answer (score 1):

No proxy needed, unity has logging crossdomain stuff built in: take a look at the [the debuging section of the unity3d manual on the security sandbox](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html) and turn on crossdomain debugging with `ENABLE_CROSSDOMAIN_LOGGING`. Then look for the results in the logs.

Just to be sure, a crossdomain file is reachable at `http://192.168.1.116:9000/crossdomain.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was implement my own version of the crossdomain.xml endpoint. It currently looks like this.

func crossdomain(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    log.Println("At the top of crossdomain")

```
if origin := req.Header.Get("Origin"); origin != "" {
    res.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
}
res.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
res.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token")
res.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")

body := "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + 
            "<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM \"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd\">" +
                "<cross-domain-policy>" +
                    "<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies=\"all\"/>" +
                    "<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\" secure=\"false\"/>" +
                    "<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\"/>" +
                    "<allow-access-from domain=\"*\"/>" +
                    "<allow-http-request-headers-from domain=\"*\"  to-ports=\"*\"/>" +
                    "<allow-http-request-headers-from domain=\"*\"/>" +
                    "<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies=\"all\"/>" +
                "</cross-domain-policy>"

io.WriteString(res,body)
```

}

func main() {

```
http.HandleFunc("/simulate", simulate)
http.HandleFunc("/crossdomain.xml", crossdomain)

listenErr := http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)
```

}